# Randoming equal values in order in R

Tags: r

I have to get order of one vector to sort other vector. The point is I don't want my function to be stable. In fact, I'd like to random order of equal values. Any idea how do it in R in finite time? :D

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it is random, what is the point of being sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Try `fct_reorder` in the `forcats` package to order one factor by another.  If you want to introduce randomness as well, try `fct_reorder2` with `.y = runif(length(your_vector))`

(I'm apparently thinking in strange directions today - `fct_reorder` will reorder the levels of a factor.  If that's what you are after, this may help.  Otherwise, `order` is the better approach.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base R using `order`. order will take multiple variable to sort on. If you make the second one be a random variable, it will randomize the ties.  Here is an example using the built-in iris data. The variable `Sepal.Length` has several ties for second lowest value. Here are some:

```
iris$Sepal.Length[c(9,39,43)]
[1] 4.4 4.4 4.4
```

Now let's sort just that variable (stable sort) and then sort with a random secondary sort.

```
order(iris$Sepal.Length)
  [1]  14   9  39  43  42   4   7  23  48   3  30  12  13  25  31  46   2  10  35
 [20]  38  58 107   5   8  26  27  36  41  44  50  61  94   1  18  20  22  24  40
 [39]  45  47  99  28  29  33  60  49   6  11  17  21  32  85  34  37  54  81  82
 [58]  90  91  65  67  70  89  95 122  16  19  56  80  96  97 100 114  15  68  83
 [77]  93 102 115 143  62  71 150  63  79  84  86 120 139  64  72  74  92 128 135
 [96]  69  98 127 149  57  73  88 101 104 124 134 137 147  52  75 112 116 129 133
[115] 138  55 105 111 117 148  59  76  66  78  87 109 125 141 145 146  77 113 144
[134]  53 121 140 142  51 103 110 126 130 108 131 106 118 119 123 136 132

order(iris$Sepal.Length, sample(150,150))
  [1]  14  43  39   9  42  48   7   4  23   3  30  25  31  46  13  12  35  38 107
 [20]  10  58   2   8  41  27  61  94   5  36  44  50  26  18  22  99  40  20  47
 [39]  24  45   1  33  60  29  28  49  85  11   6  32  21  17  90  81  91  54  34
 [58]  37  82  67 122  95  65  70  89 100  96  56 114  80  16  19  97  93  15  68
 [77] 143 102  83 115 150  62  71 120  79  84  63 139  86  72 135  74  64  92 128
 [96] 149  69  98 127  88 134 101  57 137  73 104 147 124 138 112 129 116  75  52
[115] 133 148  55 111 105 117  59  76  87  66  78 146 141 109 125 145 144 113  77
[134] 140  53 121 142  51 103 126 130 110 108 131 106 136 119 118 123 132
```

Without the random secondary sort, positions 2,3,and 4 are in order (stable).  With the random secondary sort, they are jumbled.